# ¿Por que muestra los datos como null si tengo un registro con mas de un usuario?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Nuevamente necesito de su ayuda comunidad, tengo la siguiente tabla en mi base de datos, con los registros del horario de un usuario(los rut son ficticios)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo registrados tres horarios con la misma fecha y distinta hora para un mismo usuario, si quiero consultar su disponibilidad de atención para un día x funciona correctamente, esto lo hago con la siguiente consulta.

```
select * from (
SELECT MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter, id_hr, 
fecha_registro
FROM horario
INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
WHERE usuarios.rut_usu= '17.811.942-4'
AND horario.lunes='ATTE. ESTUDIANTES' AND fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario) ORDER BY id_hr DESC LIMIT 14
) tmp order by tmp.id_hr asc
```

El resultado de esto es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, si registro el horario para otro usuario, todo ok. Pero si ejecuto la misma consulta sql anterior para el usuario que registre primero, es decir el que tiene el  rut_usu= '17.811.942-4',  Los datos me los muestra en nulo, pero si utilizo el  rut del nuevo usuario ejemplo rut_usu= '11.111.111-1' , se muestra correctamente(para ese usuario).¿Por que sucede esto ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sin ver los datos es imposible contestarlo.. pq tu problema esta en lo que devuelve alguna de las subconsultas, y para eso se necesitan los datos..

Comment: tenes un limit.. select max y min de tablas sin where... faltaria bastante informacion.

Comment: dices que falta un where aqui? SELECT MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter, id_hr, 
fecha_registro. Según tu que datos faltan? es un horario como se muestra la tabla de arriba , con esa estructura

Comment: ¿Ejecutaste todas tus subconsultas por separado con los criterios que tengan, para ver si todas arrojan datos? ¿El usuario que te muestra todo `NULL` tiene datos relacionados en `horario`?

Comment: El problema es que dices and fecha registro = (Select Max(fecha registro), eso significa que trata de encontrar la coincidencia de solo el ultimo registro, que es el que estás agregando, y por eso solo funciona para el último que agregues... no entiendo qué es lo que necesitas hacer...

Comment: Si, me acabo de dar cuenta de lo que dices, le quite esa ultima linea y muestra un resultado, aunque no el del ultimo horario para ese usuario. Te explico, lo que necesito hacer es que muestre MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter para el ultimo horario registrado de un usuario en concreto, por ejemplo para el usuario con esta clave primaria rut_usu= '17.811.942-4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta así :

```
select * from (
SELECT MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS hrs_ini, MAX(horario.hrs_ter) AS hrs_ter, id_hr, 
fecha_registro
FROM horario
INNER JOIN usuarios ON horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu
WHERE usuarios.rut_usu= '17.811.942-4'
AND horario.lunes='ATTE. ESTUDIANTES' AND fecha_registro = (SELECT MAX(fecha_registro) FROM horario where rut_usu = '17.811.942-4' ) ORDER BY id_hr DESC LIMIT 14
) tmp order by tmp.id_hr asc
```

Comment: Justamente eso era, no había notado que con esa linea mostraba solo el ultimo registro, me faltaba el Where :P , gracias.

Comment: Es bueno poder ayudar.